# Pass touch through GestureDectector inside Stack in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a Widget like this [image]

How can I touch to Yellow Widget?

Here is my code:

```dart
  Stack(
      children: [
        Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 200,
                width: 200,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 16,),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  print('Tap yellow');
                },
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  height: 200,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () async {
            print('Tap green accent');
          },
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Container(
              width: context.screenAppWidth * .5,
              height: height,
              color: Colors.greenAccent.withOpacity(0.3),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () async {
            print('Tap blue accent');
          },
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            child: Container(
              width: context.screenAppWidth * .5,
              height: height,
              color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.3),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    )
```

Comment: while you are passing size, you can wrap the Stack with GestureDetector and use localPosition to track  the tap event.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the `behavior` property of GestureDetector to `HitTestBehavior.translucent`.